# Can I make a perfect circle with a polygon clip path?

Tags: css

We have a website we've used the `-webkit-clip-path: circle()`... to make an animation, after the last Chrome/Safari updates, it doesn't work well anymore, if you haven't updated above 34 yet, you can see how it works here:

http://www.mis-implants.com//Media/Newsletters/News2014.aspx

My question is: Can I use a polygon instead of circle to get the same effect?
And if not, what technique could be used to achieve the exact same effect?

Comment: I see circles on your site in both FF29 and Chrome 35. Anyway, why not use more common `border-radius: 50%`? You can animate width or other property then.

Comment: the clip-path is used for an animation. working correctly you should see a circles with a picture, when hovering over, the circle with text will appear in circular animation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see effect you want to get, inner circle just blinks. But you always can switch from css to js animation.

Comment: Me too and why not use images instead of css3?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an element such as a DIV and giv this element fixed and equal width and height, then give this element border-radius with the double value of the width or height this will show you a perfect circle shape you check it here in the following link:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Also You can use SVG technique instead of clip path and this will be helpful for you regarding the browsers versions

Here is a link show how you can draw sharp circle also the link has addition properties for the SVG elements you can find it useful for you:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/circle-element.html

Hope this will be helpful.

Regards,